# I'm trying to change an Image's src attribute when the mouse hovers above it. Is there a reason why this JQuery code shouldn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, mouseover

```
$('.icon1').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'recursos/botban/maq1.png');
});
```

Should work right? It's just an arbitrary test to see what was wrong, but it's still broken.

I've also tried with `$('.icon1').hover(function(){...`, and it also does not work.

What I really want is more like...

```
$('.icon1').mouseover(function(){
        var alt = $(this).find('img').attr('src')+'.png';
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('id')+''.png);
}).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', alt);
});
```

The HTML for each image is as follows...

```
<a class='icon1'><img src='recursos/botban/veh1.png'></a>
```

Comment: What is `.icon1`? :) The markup would help here.

Comment: Also, are you sure using a relative path is what you want here?

Comment: @serv are you sure it is supposed to be `recursos/botban/maq1.png` and not `/recursos/botban/maq1.png`

Comment: Your img tag isn't closed, but that's probably just a typo.

Comment: Will any other javascript on the page work? You may have made a syntax error somewhere so no script is running?

Comment: @Fiona Holder: The img tag did have a typo. The JS is being loaded from a .js file, which runs fine on all other pages (this is the only bit of js that is used on this page).

Comment: @Fiona Holder: I had forgotten to import JQery on this particular page. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things, I'd use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) (since [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) will fire when entering a child), and also make sure it's running inside a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.icon1').each(function(){
    $.data(this, 'src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  }).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', this.id + '.png'); //may need adjustment
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', $.data(this, 'src'));
  });
});
```

I'm not sure *exactly* what hover image you want, but the general approach is to store what it was originally and use than then restoring it on [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).  Or, just put the `hover` on the `<img>` itself, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.icon1 img').each(function(){
    $.data(this, 'src', this.src);
  }).hover(function(){
    this.src = 'otherImage.png';
  }).mouseout(function(){
    this.src = $.data(this, 'src');
  });
});
```

Comment: It's always been running inside a document.ready, but that gives me nothing :/

Comment: @serv-bot - What *is* it doing...and are you loading this `.icon1` dynamically, e.g. via ajax?

Comment: The .icon1 are not being loaded dynamically. It's really doing nothing; the image stays static.

Comment: The images are also within a div box, although I really don't think that matters.

Comment: @serv-bot - Are there any JavaScript errors on the page? Check the console, sounds like this isn't being run at all, at least not without error.

Comment: The JS is run from within the only JS file I use on all the pages of the site. It runs ok on all other pages.

Comment: Oh dear, I forgot to import JQuery on this particular page. I feel really stupid now! Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {  // private closure;  
    $(function() {  // document load;
        $('.icon1').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', "recursos/botban/veh1.png");
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', "recursos/botban/veh2.png");
        });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had already tried this and it does not work. I stated that in my post.

Comment: are you sure these images do exist (in that path too)?

Comment: Even if they didn't, the browser should at least show the broken image symbols.